# How to add conditional if in Jenkins file for output with many lines

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to add if condition, that if i get specific output do this else do this, knowing that im getting output like this

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.17.0
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   logFile: /var/log/appium.log
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]     0: chromedriver_autodownload
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

i have used this but achive nothing

```
script{
            def appiumLog =   sh label: 'Appium log', returnStdout: true, script: "docker logs ${containerName}"
            if( appiumLog.substring(appiumLog.lastIndexOf("\n")) == '[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723') {
                     sh label: 'APK Loading', script: "docker cp src/main/resources/test.apk ${containerName}:/opt"
                     echo "APK file has copied to: ${containerName}"
            }  else {
                     echo "This is the output: ${appiumLog}"
                }
         }
```

also used this but no use

```
            if( appiumLog.indexOf('[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723') >= 0) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you are using `returnStdout: true`, make sure to always `trim()` the returned string. Most likely there is a trailing `\n` which messes up your search.

```
def appiumLog = sh( label: 'Appium log', returnStdout: true, script: "docker logs ${containerName}").trim()
```

Your first `substring()` actually returns the `\n` as first character! So you should add +1 to the index to skip the `\n`:

```
if( appiumLog.substring(appiumLog.lastIndexOf("\n") + 1) ...
```

Comment: if( appiumLog.substring(appiumLog.lastIndexOf("\n") + 1) == '[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723')

still no use it keep taking me to else function and it print nothing however im adding 

else {echo "This is the output: $appiumLog"}